# Google form responses in CSV are incorrect order

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form with responses, those with same timestamp. The responses are orderd in the way they arrived. However, when I export to csv, the order of the responses that have same timestamp differs from those of the order of responses in CSV.

Hence CSV file responses order number is not same as form responses number (not response ID, I mean to say)

Can we make a CSV data to have same response number (order) as those of form responses that are seen in the individual tab?

Comment: this is confusing -- are you saying the Google App Script endpoint is sending you data with different row order than the Google Sheet itself? If so, can you just sort on the date column to get consistent ordering?

Comment: No, I am talking about the response number without Google sheet.

Comment: The responses having same timestamps say the 3 responses arrived at same time like apple mango banana are shown in CSV, but in the reponse summary they are shown as mango, banana, apple instead of the apple mango banana.

Comment: Does it matter? If you have the timestamp of the record, you know the order they were received in. If you have the response ID, you can identify unique responses.